# Trying to get my delete button on the same line/on the right of my Challengebox component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hey! I am trying to get my delete button on the same line/on the right of my Challengebox component. Is there a way to do this with flex-wrap?**

```
.totalbox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

---

```
<div className="challengeboxes">

{    
this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
    (
        <div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>

            <Challengebox 
                key={challenge._id} 
                id={challenge._id} 
                title={challenge.title} 
                description={challenge.description}
            />

            <button onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                Delete
            </button>

        </div>
    ))                                                                      
}

</div>
```

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Can you share the screenshot of the UI? 
Ideally the current css should work.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the challengebox.css?
 .challengebox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 158px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

Comment: anyone that could help me here?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try below

```js
<div className="challengeboxes">

{    
this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
    (
        <div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>
            <div className="challenge-box-container">
               <Challengebox 
                   key={challenge._id} 
                   id={challenge._id} 
                   title={challenge.title} 
                   description={challenge.description}
               />
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                Delete
            </button>

        </div>
    ))                                                                      
}

</div>
```

```css
.totalbox .challenge-box-container {
   width: 80%;
}
```

Since I do not know what's there in `Challengebox` component I'm not able to comment is there any issue with that. So I'm just trying to wrap it in a div and provide width to that. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for trying but the button is still not on the same line/on the right...

Comment: Can you share the link of the code in fiddle or some place?